# Is the function $f(n,m)=n^2+m^2$ in $O(nm)$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I am trying to solve a problem related to big o with two variables. I'll write the exercise below.

Prove or disprove the statement:  *$n^2+m^2=O(nm)$*

Just in case, I'll write one definition needed:

Let $f,g:\mathbb N^k \to \mathbb N$, we say $f \in O(g)$ if and only if there are some numbers $c \in \mathbb N$ and $\overrightarrow{n_0} \in \mathbb N^k$ such that for all $\overrightarrow{n} >\overrightarrow{n_0}$,$$f(\overrightarrow{n}) \leq cg(\overrightarrow{n})$$

where $\overrightarrow{n_1} > \overrightarrow{n_2}$ if and only if $n_{1_i} > n_{2_i}$ for all $i=1,...,k$.

I think that this statement is false but I couldn't write a formal proof of this. I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I agree the statement is false. This can be done directly. First you need to Fix $c$. Then you need to pick an $n$ and $m$ such that for any $\vec n \geq (n,m)$ you have $$f(\vec n)> cg(\vec n).$$

Answer (score 1):

It is false.  For any $c$ and any $(m_0, n_0)$, take $m= m_0+1$ and note that
$m^2 + n^2 > c m n$ if $n$ is sufficiently large.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If $m = 1$,
then
$n^2+m^2 > n^2$
and
$mn = n = O(n)$.

However,
if $m = \Theta(n)$
(so $an < m < bn$
for some $a, b > 0$),
then
$n^2+m^2
= O(nm)$
since
$ n^2+m^2
\lt (m/a)^2+m^2
=m^2(1+1/a^2)
<mnb(1+1/a^2)
$.